# Submit button removes "select2-container-active" from the class attribute

Tags: jquery, html, validation, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a form which needs custom validation (bootstrap selects don't play nicely with JQuery.validate). The main rule in this form is that no drop-down menu can be left unselected. I've inferred that when I select a drop-down item, the `class` attribute of my drop-down div receives a `select2-container-active` suffix, which enables me to write a custom JQuery selector:

```
 function validateSelect(id) {
    var result = {
        valid: $(id).hasClass("select2-container-active"),
        element: id
    }
    return result;
}
```

This fetches every valid (selected) drop-down menu which enables me to determine if there are any invalid drop-downs. The problem is that when I hit the submit button, the suffix gets removed from the `class` attribute before I have a chance to invoke the `validateSelect` method. It gets invoked, and doesn't find the suffix, and therefore "thinks" that no drop-down item is selected, even though I've selected an item in every drop-down menu.

How can I prevent the button from removing this suffix upon submission(clicking)?

**edit:**
Here's the HTML for one of the drop-downs:

```
<div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="selectInsert02">City:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select name="citiesSelect" id="selectInsert02" class="input-xlarge with-search" data-bind="foreach: certificationModel.citiesList" required>
                        <option data-bind="text: Name, value: CityID"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The code you've posted shouldn't remove any classes. Does bootstrap add that class to the drop downs? if it's automatic, it seems like it's something that gets added when that particular container is active, so when you click away from it the class is removed.  You can verify this by looking at the elements tab in your debugger.  click the dropdown menu, it should get that class.  click away, the class should go away.  can you provide the HTML/javascript that you use to create the dropdowns? We may be able to suggest another way around.

Comment: You're right. Even when I click into the empty space in the form, the class suffix gets removed. It's probably something bootstrap related. I will paste the code. Stand by, please.

Comment: The way I see it you have 2 options: one: create a default option that isn't a valid option like "--select--", verify that that option isn't selected.  two: create an "onclick" handler that verifies a correct option has been set and then assigns a class like "selected" that you check against (in that handler you should remove the "selected" class if it exists but a correct option isn't selected)

Comment: @Snowburnt thanks, I will try something like option 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it you have 2 options: one: create a default option that isn't a valid option like "--select--", verify that that option isn't selected. two: create an "onclick" handler that verifies a correct option has been set and then assigns a class like "selected" that you check against (in that handler you should remove the "selected" class if it exists but a correct option isn't selected)